# Setting Checkbox ItemStyle ForeColor on ASP.Net DetailsView and GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox, detailsview, foreground

On an ASP.Net DetailsView and also on a GridView I noticed that the tick mark in CheckBoxes are a light gray (disabled) colour even though I set it as blue.

```
<asp:CheckBoxField DataField="DayOfWeekMonday" HeaderText="Monday:" SortExpression="DayOfWeekMonday">
    <ItemStyle ForeColor="Blue" />
</asp:CheckBoxField>
```

The same thing happens when the CheckBox is a TemplateField.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Monday:" SortExpression="DayOfWeekMonday">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxEditDayOfWeekMonday" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("DayOfWeekMonday") %>' />
    </EditItemTemplate>

    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxInsertDayOfWeekMonday" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("DayOfWeekMonday") %>' />
    </InsertItemTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxItemDayOfWeekMonday" runat="server" Checked='<%# Bind("DayOfWeekMonday") %>' Enabled="false" />
    </ItemTemplate>

    <ItemStyle ForeColor="Blue" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I also tried this in the code-behind file.

```
Protected Sub CheckBoxItemDayOfWeekMonday_DataBinding(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Dim theControl As CheckBox

    theControl = DetailsView.FindControl("CheckBoxItemDayOfWeekMonday")
    theControl.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Blue

End Sub
```

Is there a way to change it to blue like the rest of our fields and columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed you meant the tick mark INSIDE the checkboxes, not the forecolor. I don't think you can change this as this is very OS dependant. I have implemented this with images in the past. You can try these CSS3 CheckBoxes which uses images: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Sample:

**HTML**:

```
<span><input type="checkbox" id="c1" name="cc" />
<label for="c1"><span></span>Check Box 1</label>
</span>
```

**CSS**:

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display:none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label {
    color:#000000;
    font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label span {
    display:inline-block;
    width:19px;
    height:19px;
    margin:-1px 4px 0 0;
    vertical-align:middle;
    background:url(http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/391_checkboxes/check_radio_sheet.png) left top no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label span {
    background:url(http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/391_checkboxes/check_radio_sheet.png) -19px top no-repeat;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4FraV/2/

Comment: Thanks Hanlet. I will try the CSS way. :-)

Comment: You are welcome. If the colors don't match yours, you will just have to modify the images.

Comment: Looks like input does not work with a DetailsView. I got this error: System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection must have items of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlField'. 'input' is of type 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputCheckBox'. Also, how do you bind the data to this? asp:CheckBoxField will bind the data but I don't know how to do it with input.

Comment: As a workaround you can add the input to a WebUserControl and then add this to your DetailsView and/or Gridview controls.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you give instructions on how to "add the input to a WebUserControl" ? Thanks.

Comment: Before I do that, would you try to make this input element runat="server" and assign it an id? I think this could make the trick.

Comment: It still give the same error with runat="server". I used: <input type="checkbox" id="DayOfWeekTuesday" name="cc" runat="server" />
                    <label for="c1">
                        <span></span>Check Box 1
                    </label>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23252/discussion-between-hanlet-escano-and-emad-ud-deen)

Comment: above asked for <asp:Checkboxlist> control. For Html Case All Known http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons/

Comment: if you know post for asp controls